# how to compute the cardinality of $C_n$?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

Let $U$ be a set , $C$ be the set generated from $B$ by two functions $f , g$ where $B$ $\subset$ $U$

$B =\{a,b\}$

$$f:U\times  U\to U $$

$$g: U \to U $$

Let $C_n$ be the set of points such that some construction sequence of length $n$ ends with some $x$

A construction sequence is a finite sequence $(X_1,X_2,\dots X_n )$ of elements of $U$ such that , for each $i$ less than or equal to $n$ , we have at least one of

$X_i \in  B$

$X_i=f(X_j,X_k)$ for some $j,k$ less than $i$

$X_i=g(X_j)$ for some $j$ less than $i$

My question: what is the most possible number of elements of $C_n$ which can exist?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a partial answer.

First, let's write out a couple of the $C_i$, to get a feel for the problem:

$$
\begin{align}C_1 = \{ a , b \}\\
C_2 = \{ a,b, g(a), g(b), f(a,a), f(a,b), f(b,a), f(b,b) \} \\
C_3 = C_2 \cup \{ g(x) | x \in C_2 \} \cup \{ f(y,z) | y \in C_2, z \in C_2 \}
\end{align}$$

and so on. But the unions in the latter equation are not disjoint! To count them, you have 
to look at the new elements in each 'generation'. So let's define $D_n = C_n - C_{n-1}$, we have:

$$
\begin{align}D_1 = \{ a , b \}\\
D_2 = \{ g(a), g(b), f(a,a), f(a,b), f(b,a), f(b,b) \} \\
D_3 = \{ g(x) | x \in C_2 \} \cup \{ f(y,z) | y \in C_2, z \in C_2 \}
\end{align}$$

Notice that the number of $f$'s and $g$'s of each element in $D_n$ is equal to $n-1$, so these sets are disjoint. It's easy to figure out an equation for the number of elements of $D_n$, let's call it $d(n)$:

$$
\begin{align}d(0)=2\\
d(n) = d(n-1) + d(n-1)^2
\end{align}
$$

The answer to your question is now that $|C_n| = \sum_{i=0}^{n} d(n)$, but at the moment I'm stuck finding a closed form for $d(n)$ or for $|C_n|$. The quadratic term is dominant, so we can at least say that $d(n) \ge 2^{2^n}$, but that's all I've got so far...